# If $K$ is a compact set and $x_{n}$ is a sequence. Will the sequence converge iff it is cauchy? If yes, how can I prove it?

Tags: general-topology

If $K$ is a compact set in the metric space $(X, d_{X})$ and $x_{n}$ is a sequence in $K$. I have to prove that the sequence converge only if it is Cauchy.

Comment: Indeed it will.

Comment: Hi Saucy. Thanks. How can I prove that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.